# ABS.STAT API JSON for new period data

Tags: json, powerquery

i am trying to automate downloading online statistics into my financial models.
i am using australian statistics database http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/index.aspx? to automatically pull cpi data via an api json link converted into a power query and excel's "get data from web" functionality.
however, i can only bring the existing data, but can't make it add a new period of data when it's published on the website. i'd be happy with either adding new data column or replacing existing data e.g. so that i always have last four quarters.
i'm not an expert and i can't find anything useful because i'm probably not using the right terms in my google search!
any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: I may be trying to grasp something I don't understand. You are trying to make excel update whenever the website is updated?

Comment: Indeed, I am trying to make excel update whenever the website is updated. But my concern is when the website is updated with new data for new time periods, not when historical data for current time periods is revised.